# Может кто подключал телефон Xiapmi mi 3 в режиме разработчика?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Так чтобы можно было на устройстве отладку приложений вести, на старом своём андройде китайском это делалось легко в опциях, достаточно было установить драйвер, а как на этом не пойму. Подскажите кто в теме, нагуглил какие то универсальные драйвера https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver не знаю помогут или нет, пока тыкаюсь как слепой. Да в инженерное меню входил, там где 7 раз кликать тоже не особо помогло.

На эмуляторе такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эмулятор так и не заработал
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Непосредственно отладкой не занимался, но по крайней мере `adb` телефон видит, подключается, и все такое. После разблокирования меню "Для разработчиков" (многократным нажатием на версию MIUI в разделе "О телефоне"), в этом самом меню надо непосредственно включить "режим разработчика", а также разрешить "отладку по USB". Вроде как больше ничего не требуется.

Comment: Да разрулил эту загадку, в общем кликаешь 7 раз получаешь сообщение о том что включён режим бога, переходишь в доп настройки там появляется пунктик, жмёшь врубить отладку, ну остальное по дефолту